# Error in as.dendrogram

Tags: r, dendrogram, hclust

I am trying to make a dendrpgram using large data

I am using the **stats**, **phyclust** libraries,

```
distances <- phyclust.edist(Data[,],edist.model = .edist.model[3]) 
dataHClust <- hclust(distances, "ave")
dhc <- as.dendrogram(dataHClust)
```

`hclust` works fine and I can plot it and it plots it properly.
After I use the `as.dendrogram` function it doesn't give me an error. But when I either:

- try to plot it
- use `dendrapply` to apply functions.

it says:

```
Error in lapply(args, is.character) : node stack overflow 
Error in dev.flush() : node stack overflow
```

Is the problem with  as.dendrogram not being able to handle large datasets (~30000)?
If so, is there an alternative to it?

Comment: Can you please add your code(how you call dendrapply?) and some data to reproduce the error?

Comment: Your solution is probably here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559250/error-in-heatmap-2-gplots

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a problem with plotting a large dataset because I was able to get your code to run on a small dataset.

You could try cutting the dendrogram to get it to fit in a plot with the `h` or `height` parameter in `as.dendrogram`.